# How to increase width of BottomNavigationView to fill the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How to increase width of BottomNavigationView menu. Below is the current scenario. I am not able to increase the width to complete screen.

[image]

Menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.idea.nikhil.googlemaps.bottomNavigationbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

That is doable (**Even without reflection**). But it will againts [default design specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage), and I wil suggest you to go with [default design specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage).

---

> Now coming to my solution...

Define below dimensions into `dimens.xml`. These dimensions should be in `values`, `values-large`, `values-large-land` and `600dp` can be increased to `1000dp` or more in `values-large`, `values-large-land`, if in tablet you are not seeing this change.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And thats it!!! Result will be like [image]

---

It's not a mazic.

> Why dimensions has been added with such name and value is 600dp

Both dimensions is being used by `BottomNavigationMenuView.java` (which is the class being used to represent menu in `BottomNavigationView`).
Below is code

```
public BottomNavigationMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...
    mInactiveItemMaxWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width);
    ....
    mActiveItemMaxWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width);
    .....
}
```

Now these values is being used to create view with fixed width, as below

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    ....
    if (mShiftingMode) {
        final int inactiveCount = count - 1;
        final int activeMaxAvailable = width - inactiveCount * mInactiveItemMinWidth;
        final int activeWidth = Math.min(activeMaxAvailable, mActiveItemMaxWidth);
        final int inactiveMaxAvailable = (width - activeWidth) / inactiveCount;
        final int inactiveWidth = Math.min(inactiveMaxAvailable, mInactiveItemMaxWidth);
        ...
    } else {
        final int maxAvailable = width / count;
        final int childWidth = Math.min(maxAvailable, mActiveItemMaxWidth);
        .....
    }
    ....
}
```

To use value of `activeMaxAvailable` always, I set a dummy value to `mActiveItemMaxWidth` (in dimens above). So `activeWidth` will have
value of `activeMaxAvailable`. Same rule apply for `inactiveWidth`.

So when you build project, `design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width` and `design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width` defined
into *design-support-lib*, will be replaced by dimensions defined by us.

**Code verified on maximum supported options (5 max) also.**

Answer (score 1):

i dont remember where i found this solution exactly but you use this helper class to disable item shifting for BottomNavigation using Java Reflection :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(Context context,BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);

                Field LargeText = item.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLargeLabel");
                LargeText.setAccessible(true);
                Field SmallText = item.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSmallLabel");
                SmallText.setAccessible(true);

//                 TextView SmallTextView =(TextView) SmallText.get(item);
//                 TextView LargeTextView =(TextView) LargeText.get(item);

//                 Typeface tf = TypefaceHelper.getTypeface(context);
//                 SmallTextView.setTypeface(tf);
//                 LargeTextView.setTypeface(tf);

                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the BottomNavigationView specs:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#specs-figure-caption-17

Your navigation is correctly, but if anyway you want to expand the padding between the elements I recommend that you create your own bottom navigation using something like FlexBoxLayout: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout