# How to increase the width of one item in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I have BottomNavigationView in Android that has equal spacing among the items and I'd like to change the size of one of the items in the menu. I'm looking for something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318813/2997806 but for one item. Here's my menu atm:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/item1"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/item2"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:icon="item3"
        android:title=""/>
</menu>
```

And BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

Comment: hi waseefakhtar did you got solution for this .

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:itemIconSize="?dp"
                app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

Comment: But this increases the size of icons, and all of them at once. I don't want to increase the size of icons. I just want to increase the width of one of them.

Comment: you can control your item icons size in your code. This is just an example. If you want to set default value of your item icon size, you can set like this. But if you want to change it according to your actions, you can change it programatically.But the second part of your question in your comment, If you find something, please set here :)