# Blank space either side of BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I'm creating an Android app with a BottomNavigationView and for some reason there is blank space on either side so it doesn't fill the whole width of the screen. It's not padding, because I removed the padding and I can see the shadow of the bottom view separating the blank area from the space above. Why are my four menu items not filling the entire width of the screen?

It looks good when I have three or five items so is this just a limitation of dividing the screen space into even numbers?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorNavTint"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorNavText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

navigation Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_discover"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_discover"
        android:title="Discover"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_messages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_messages"
        android:title="Messages"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_orders"
        android:title="Orders"/>

</menu>
```

and the parent ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole XML layout where BottomNavigation is?

Comment: It's inside this ConstraintLayout:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: Did you try changing the root layout? Does that do anything? Is it showing your 4 buttons in the bottom navigation? You don't programmatically do anything to these layouts? The last resort to consider is to programmatically find the device screen width and setting that width to bottom navigation or coloring the background behind buttons with the same color. Not a great solution but I can't think of anything else. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318813/14759470

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I will check it out. I will mark the question Solved.